# Is there a way to construct database query, where I can apply condition based on values in a list?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var contacts = await dbContext.Registration.Where(x => visited.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)
                && visited.Any(y => (x.OutDate >= y.InDate && x.OutDate <= y.OutDate)
                || (x.InDate >= y.InDate && x.OutDate <= y.OutDate)
                || (x.InDate >= y.InDate && x.InDate <= y.OutDate)
                || (x.InDate <= y.InDate && x.OutDate >= y.OutDate)))
                .ToListAsync()
```

This query gives error that, "The LINQ Query could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()."

Here ***visited is a list of Object that has property Id, InDate and OutDate***.
Visited has been already fetched from DB and is present in ,memory.
I want to filter my database results based on the values present in these objects.

One way could be Iterating through each object and getting all tuples according to a single object and repeating the same for other objects in the list. This would involve multiple Network Calls and would be very inefficient.

Is there any way in which I get all the results in 1 Network call ?

Comment: is visited list loaded before ? do they have any relation in DB?

Comment: No, It has already been fetched from DB and resides in memory now.

Comment: `visited` is a c# collection and you are using it in a LINQ query of EF which will eventually translate to SQL to run against database. While these translation is happening it is not able to translate `visited` to SQL that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: One option is to do `await dbContext.Registration.ToList().Where(.....` this will not give you error but it will select all the data from registration table into memory. That might impact the performance of the code.

Comment: If you have Visited Table also available in the database then you can do join between Registration and Visited tables. That's the other option

Comment: You need to pass through the list to the DB as a TVP, which I don't believe can be done with LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that x.OutDate > x.InDate and y.OutDate > y.InDate you can reduce to following :

```
             var contacts = dbContext.Registration.SelectMany(x => visited.Where(y => (y.Id == x.Id)
                && ((x.InDate >= y.InDate && x.OutDate <= y.OutDate)
                || (x.InDate <= y.InDate && x.OutDate >= y.OutDate))));
```

---

Where comparing two ranges of dates there are 7 combinations

[image]

Comment: Processing of the LINQ expression 'x => __visited_0
    .Where(y => y.Id == x.Id && x.InDate >= y.InDate && x.OutDate <= y.OutDate || x.InDate <= y.=InDate && x.OutDate >= y.OutDate)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

based on part of your statement I assume that `visited` is somewhere persisted in db.

therefore visited could be queried

```
//requery visitations;
var visited = dbContext.Visited.Where(v=> v.visited).Select(v=> {v.Id, v.InDate, v.OutDate })
```

and then registration query

```
var query = dbContext.Registration
            .Join(visited, 
                reg => reg.Id,
                visit => visit.Id,
                (reg, visit) => new {Registration = reg, Visit = visit})
            .Where(regAndVisit =>
                (regAndVisit.Registration.OutDate >= regAndVisit.Visit.InDate &&
                 regAndVisit.Registration.OutDate <= regAndVisit.Visit.OutDate)
                || (regAndVisit.Registration.InDate >= regAndVisit.Visit.InDate &&
                    regAndVisit.Registration.OutDate <= regAndVisit.Visit.OutDate)
                || (regAndVisit.Registration.InDate >= regAndVisit.Visit.InDate &&
                    regAndVisit.Registration.InDate <= regAndVisit.Visit.OutDate)
                || (regAndVisit.Registration.InDate <= regAndVisit.Visit.InDate &&
                    regAndVisit.Registration.OutDate >= regAndVisit.Visit.OutDate));
```

possible to add `GroupBy` or `Distinct` if you want to avoid duplicated not sure what is connection between visits and registration